# asp.net c# MVC 5-Log off the active directory user

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, logout

I have my application(with individual user account authentication type)to use active directory login in my custom login screen using the LDAP connection with System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

I can login into the application, but I am not able to logout from the application.

Here is my logoff code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

My web.config file is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionUsername="ldapnew" connectionPassword="abcd123!" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://10.0.1.10:379/ou=General,dc=abc,dc=local" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please help me to resolve this code?

Answer (score 0):

We're doing this different, you have to redirect to the ADFS signout page it self...